# coundown server-side implementation

Tags: java, javascript, spring, counter

On client-side we have JS counter in typical format:

xx days xx hours xx minutes xx seconds left

And it keeps counting. Whenever counter reaches zero I would like to automatically close the registration for an event.

What I don't get is how to synchronize time both on server side and client side, so that cron job would be carried with at least minute precision accounting for time zone. Do I need to? What else do I need apart from 'date' 'time' 'locale' in the database?

The context is web application on Java + Spring + Postgresql

I don't need the entire solution - rather good hints(or links) on where to start digging.

Comment: What do you mean synchronize the time? Are you already counting down on both client **and** server at the moment and they are counting out of sync based on a timezone, for example?

Comment: On the server side you shouldn't be keeping a counter, or even a cron job. Just check the time when you get a registration, if it's too late, respond with an error message, otherwise continue on.

Comment: I second Thor84no's suggestion

Comment: Thor, please put that as an answer so I can accept. Though it sounds like very obvious we tend to overcomplicate things.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

- Set the page to autorefresh
- Periodically send an AJAX request to resync.

However ...

- In reality, it would be surprising for the client and server-side clocks to drift appreciably over a couple of hours.  A half-decent PC won't drift more than a handful of seconds a day.
- Syncing clocks accurately over the internet is a not trivial problem, and probably not one that you are going to solve using an HTTP-based service.

Taking these two together, I think that rsyncing the timers is probably not going to be worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to let server know when countdown has ended on client side, all you need to do is send an AJAX request when countdown is done.

Answer (score 0):

Just refuse to send the information from the client if the timer expired

```
//have customer enter entry information

if (endtime > system.currentTimeMillis())
{
    // accept entry
    Outputstream.Write(Entry)
{

else
{
    "Sorry Registration Closed"
}
```

The other way to do this is to countdown on the server end and reject entry if it's too late.

```
Entry = Inputstream();
if (system.currentTimeMillis() < endtime)
{
    myEntries[x] = Entry;
    response = "Entry accepted!"
}
else
{
    response = "Entry denied: Registration closed"
}

Outputstream.write(response);
```